# Using index in merge update in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-update, sql-merge

I have query like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1 USING
  (SELECT t2.id ,
          t2.updated ,
          t2.data
   FROM table2 t2) sel ON (sel.id = t1.id
                           AND sel.updated = t1.updated) WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET t1.data = sel.data;
```

In plan I see INDEX FULL SCAN on table2 and **TABLE ACCESS FULL** on table1. Then this tables join using HASH JOIN. Both tables have indexes including id, updated and data fields.

Is there any way to remove **TABLE ACCESS FULL** and use faster way to access table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the goal to change the plan or to improve the performance?  If you're going to need to read every row from `table1`, a table scan is a pretty efficient way to do that.  It sounds like you're reflexively equating table scans with poor performance which isn't generally true-- table scans can be quite efficient in these sorts of contexts.

If there was an index on `table1( id, updated, data )` and that index was smaller than the table (i.e. there are other columns in `table1` that aren't involved in the query), I'd guess that the optimizer would choose to do a full scan on that index as well.  That's probably not going to generate a much more efficient query but it would remove the table scan.